# macOS, Carbon.framework, How to register a new input source with TISRegisterInputSource method

Tags: objective-c, macos, keyboard-layout

[image]I want to register a new keyboard layout bundle with `TISRegisterInputSource` method available in Carbon.framework. I have read the documentation but I cannot use that method correctly.
I haven't found any example of how to use it.

Comment: Are you sure you mean Carbon and not Cocoa? Carbon isn't supported anymore.

Comment: @Mgetz I have updated and added a screenshot, as you can see it's a part of Carbon and  HIToolbox frameworks